# Assign cells to a variable with Openpyxl

Tags: python, export-to-excel, openpyxl

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook,workbook   
book = load_workbook('myfile.xlsx')
sheet = book.get_active_sheet()
for r in sheet.rows:
    for cell in r:
       firstname = cell.value(row=r, column='1')
       lastname = cell.value(row=r, column='2')
       print firstname, lastname
```

I want to assign each cell value on the current row to a seperate variable. When I try the above code I get the error:

> TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I've figured out where I failed here, as embarassed as I am to admit it!

When I checked what values I was actually trying to feed Openpyxl the error was clear, the "r" variable was a string full of data rather than an integer. Using a simple "rowcount" like..

```
rowcount = 0
for r in ws.rows:
    firstname = ws.cell(row = rowcount, column = 0)
    lastname = ws.cell(row = rowcount, column = 1)
    rowcount = rowcount + 1
    print firstname.value, lastname.value
```

Seems to have done the trick.